# python pandas assign value to dataframe according to the previous row values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to assign a restarting index to a pandas dataframe with python, like column `position` below. it should restart every time the keyword is different from the line before.

| keyword | date | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| keyword1 | 2023-09-10 | 1 |
| keyword1 | 2023-09-10 | 2 |
| keyword1 | 2023-09-10 | 3 |
| keyword1 | 2023-09-10 | 4 |
| keyword1 | 2023-09-10 | 5 |
| keyword222 | 2023-09-10 | 1 |
| keyword222 | 2023-09-10 | 2 |
| keyword222 | 2023-09-10 | etc. |

I tried using apply method but fail to reference the previous line.

Comment: `df["position"] = df.groupby("keyword").cumcount().add(1)`.

Comment: Hello, @Maria could you share your code and the results? It's better to understand and help you!